# Assigning a variable declared as integer to a formula

Tags: vba

I'm trying to use a variable inside a formula, which has previously been declared as integer in the code, can someone help me with this matter?

So basically I have:

```
  Dim R_count As Integer

  R_count = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

which counts the number of row. Then I am trying to use the `variable R_count` in the `min` formula as being the bottom of my range, such as:

```
Range("n2").FormulaR1C1 = "=min((RC[-9]:R[&R_count]c[-9]))"
```

but VBa does not read `R_count` as an integer in the formula.

Comment: as a side note: you'd better declare `Dim R_count As Long` since you could exceed the integer type maximum value (some 32 k or so)

Answer (score 1):

Your value you are assigning for your range is a string, so you will need to concatenate the string formula with your variable. Try the following:

`Range("n2").FormulaR1C1 = "=min((RC[-9]:R[" & R_count & "]c[-9]))"`

[Concatenating in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx)

Comment: HI Chase, I still get a compile error with that ... many thanks for ur time

Comment: @Km1 my guess is you were using the non edited formula.  make sure you refresh your screen.  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly reference variables from vba in a formula, because the formula is a string that will be evaluated in a different place that does not know about your code. You will need to insert the value in your formula like so :

```
Range("n2").FormulaR1C1 = "=min((RC[-9]:R[" & R_count & "]c[-9]))"
```

Which will produce a formula that will look like this (lets assume that `R_Count` is equal to 42 for this exemple)

```
=min((RC[-9]:R[42]c[-9]))
```

Comment: That works fine ..... so basically by using "& xxxx &" u transforming the string into the integer it was previously assigned ? Many thanks for u time

Comment: @Km1 the `xxxx` can be (almost) any variable. It will always convert the value to a string automaticly